# Matrix Calculus Partial Derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Can anyone explain the partial derivative below:

$\frac{\partial a^tX^{-1}b}{\partial X} = -X^{-t}ab^tX^{-t}$

I was trying to derive this equation using the below formula, but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = X^{-1}$, since it's easier to type.

Taking the differential of $I=Y\cdot X$ you'll find that 
$$dY = -Y\cdot dX\cdot Y$$

Now rearrange $a'\cdot Y\cdot b$ into $ab':Y$ and take the differential
$$\eqalign{
d(ab':Y) &= ab':dY \cr
         &= -ab':(Y\cdot dX\cdot Y) \cr
         &= -(Y'\cdot ab'\cdot Y'):dX \cr
}$$
Passing to the derivative
$$
\frac{\partial(ab':Y)}{\partial X} = -(Y'\cdot ab'\cdot Y')
$$

Comment: what is the ":" stands for here?

Comment: There are several names for it. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you might consider computing the derivative of $f(X)=a^TX^{-1}b$,

\begin{align}
f(X+H)=a^T(X+H)^{-1}b&=a^T((I+HX^{-1})X)^{-1}b\\[10pt]
&=a^TX^{-1}(I+HX^{-1})^{-1}b\\[1pt]
&=a^{T}X^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(HX^{-1})^nb
\end{align}

Where the final equality follows from the closed form for the matrix geometric series.

For $\|H\|$ small,

$$a^{T}X^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(HX^{-1})^nb\approx a^{T}X^{-1}(I-HX^{-1})b=\underbrace{a^{T}X^{-1}b}_{f}+\underbrace{(-a^{T}X^{-1}HX^{-1}b)}_{\nabla_Hf}$$

Now to determine $\nabla f$, we need to write $\nabla_Hf$ as a matrix inner product,

$$\nabla_Hf=-a^{T}X^{-1}HX^{-1}b=-\text{tr}(X^{-1}ba^TX^{-1}H)=\langle -X^{-T}ab^TX^{-T},\; H\rangle\\[1pt]$$

Therefore $\nabla f=-X^{-T}ab^TX^{-T}$.

Answer (score 0):

A totally mechanical approach. By the chain rule:

$$\frac{∂a^⊤ X^{-1} b}{∂ X} = \frac{∂a^⊤ X^{-1} b}{∂ X^{-1}}∘\frac{∂X^{-1} }{∂ X}$$

Consider the first term $\frac{∂a^⊤ X^{-1} b}{∂ X^{-1}}$. Note that the nominator is linear in $X^{-1}$, therefore its derivative is found directly by bringing it to the standard form of a linear function "$x↦A⋅x$":

$$a^⊤ X^{-1} b = ⟨ab^⊤∣X^{-1}⟩ ⟹ \frac{∂a^⊤ X^{-1} b}{∂ X^{-1}} = ab^⊤$$

Secondly, let's figure out $\frac{∂X^{-1}}{∂ X}$ first. Note that

$$ X⋅X^{-1} =  ⟹  \frac{d}{dX}(X⋅X^{-1}) =0$$

Apply product rule:

$$\begin{aligned}
0 = \frac{d}{dX}(X⋅X^{-1}) 
&= \frac{∂\, Y⋅Z}{∂(Y, Z)}\Bigg|_{\begin{aligned}Y&=X\\ Z&=X^{-1}\end{aligned}} \cdot
\frac{∂(X, X^{-1})}{∂X}
\\&= \begin{bmatrix}⊗X^{-⊤},\, X⊗\end{bmatrix}⋅\begin{bmatrix}⊗\\ \frac{∂X^{-1}}{∂ X}\end{bmatrix}
\\&= (⊗X^{-⊤}) + (X⊗)\frac{∂X^{-1}}{∂ X}
\\⟹ \frac{∂X^{-1}}{∂ X} &= -(X⊗)^{-1}(⊗X^{-⊤})
\\&= -(X^{-1}⊗)(⊗X^{-⊤}) = -X^{-1}⊗X^{-⊤}
\end{aligned}$$

That is, $\frac{∂X^{-1}}{∂ X}$ is the linear map $V↦ (-X^{-1}⊗X^{-⊤})⋅V = -X^{-1}VX^{-1}$

---

Putting both together we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂a^⊤ X^{-1} b}{∂ X^{-1}}∘\frac{∂X^{-1} }{∂ X}
&= (V↦  ⟨ab^⊤∣V⟩) ∘ (V↦  -X^{-1}VX^{-1})
\\ &= (V↦  ⟨ab^⊤∣-X^{-1}VX^{-1}⟩) 
\\ &= (V↦  ⟨-X^{-⊤}ab^⊤X^{-⊤}∣V⟩) 
\end{aligned}$$